# Remove last part of URL with regex

Tags: regex, nginx

I have lot of URL links that looks like:

https://www.example.com/category/product_name?product_rewrite=product_name

I am trying to redirect them to:

https://www.example.com/category/product_name

I have a module in Prestashop where I can put regex for redirect old to new URL.

I am trying with:

OLD URL: https://www.example.com/(.*)\?product_rewrite=(.*)

New URL: https://www.exampe.com/(.*)\

Unfortunately above is not working and can not find why - because module is not working properly or because I am giving wrong data.

Comment: Do you want the new url to be without those additional parameters (those followed by `?`)?

Comment: Yes. Right now google indexed my site in format https://www.example.com/category_name/product_name?product_rewrite=product_name As you can understand - I have duplicated product name in URL and want to remove one of it.